# Community view on recall notices

Tags: discussion

[Why is a Kraft String Cheese recall important to dog owners/trainers? (since deleted)](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/975/why-is-a-kraft-string-cheese-recall-important-to-dog-owners-trainers) raises a concern that may affect any of us with pets: getting the word of a recall affecting our friends out there.

Did we want to look at a means to help this?

The Photography site has a custom header feature that allows for moderators to provide custom content (usually a picture of the week contest), so did we want to request a similar feature for the purposes of providing short-lived, but important, notices to the community in this regards?

Comment: If we do, creating an event in the community bulletin would be one way to do it that doesn't require any code changes.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I think the functionality is there already, either way. I was just thinking that we might want a vehicle for such a thing, one way or another, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, people would ultimately need a way to suggest things to appear there, so consensus on a vehicle does seem prudent.

Comment: Another thing to consider - will we post recalls from any country? Like I am in Canada, for example, so American recalls won't always affect me, but Canadian ones might.

Comment: @AshleyNunn - I don't know. The post that triggered this suffered from geographic (and time) scope issues. Having said that, it's a pretty big, and relevant, geography and the information about it may alert other people to consider things they may have ignored. At any rate, it's not the first like this, so I'm wondering about it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if these will really work. What remains is, in order to use the system to draw attention to them for the brief amount of time that they'd be relevant, folks would have to:

1. Post the information here on meta
2. Ask that the post be featured so it shows up in the bulletin
3. Alarm quite a few people where the recall probably doesn't apply

That just gets rather wonky.

At that point, the notices would need to be cleaned up, and that's not even mentioning whatever convention we'd come up with to determine which ones were important enough to show.

That said, if a *major* recall happened, as in Purina realized that it accidentally put LSD in all of its food distributed to every major vendor in the world - there would *surely* be a bunch of more on-topic questions about it that also drew attention to the recall and circumstances around it.

When Pets gets through the public beta period (a while down the road, but worth mentioning), it'll also have a blog if enough folks in the community want to write for it. The blog would be a *much* more appropriate venue for this sort of thing. Our chat room is also pretty active, so there's that as well.

Don't *not* ask a question about a recall if it retains value after the recall has ended, and applies to a relatively broad demographic - but I don't think there's going to be too many instances of that.

Comment: bloody hell.. whenever you post, I know you'll get 653 upvotes and I wasted my time posting.  hahahahha

Comment: Wait, how do you _know_ it's going to be 653? Did we re-open the time travel proposal on Area 51 a few years from now? _WHAT ELSE DO YOU KNOW MAN?_

Comment: I generally agree, actually, but since there's been a few "questions" aimed at delivering this info, I figure I would pose the idea.

Comment: @JohnCavan Worth posting, I think. The sites we compete with have / allow this sort of thing, and I think it's important to gauge how people feel about arriving at a more focused sort of resource vs what they've been using.

Comment: I sculpted the question (in question) to have lasting value, but I can only assume downvoters saw the word "recall" and recoiled.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we need to become a repository for recall notices. There are websites dedicated to this; and it is already, somewhat, covered here [How can I keep track of pet food recalls?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/478/how-can-i-keep-track-of-pet-food-recalls). It's important to remember it's a global community and it could become an overly comprehensive list.

Listing recalls is not unlike [Let's go shopping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136648/should-lets-close-old-recommendation-questions) questions.

The Stack Exchange blog [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) says of this type of question:

> ... **will be utterly obsolete within a year!** What’s the point of a bunch of labor intensive questions that provide only temporary benefit to a limited (some might say Too Localized) audience?

Comment: My thinking was a short lived banner notice, nothing more.